# Managing several NodeJS servers

Tags: node.js, phantomjs, scalability

I have a Rails app which uses PhantomJS in order to parse pages. I have moved the PhantomJS parser into a NodeJS server. Since PhantomJS is expensive to process, I just have one PhantomJS instance per CPU (using the cluster within a server).

Now, I want to be able to have more machines with NodeJS, and from Rails be able to just say: hey, process this URL. Right now is working with just one machine. But I don't know how would you structure this multi-server NodeJS servers.

So, right now whenever I want to parse a site, I send a request to my NodeJS machine, and once that has been parsed, NodeJS posts backs to Rails. But, how do you scale parallely with multiple servers in NodeJS, in a way that it is clever enough to when a URL is received it is sent to the server that has less jobs processing?

Comment: it's called load balancing so you need a load balancer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, you'll need to build a proxy server on top of your application servers to handle the routing of traffic.

Not sure which hosting provider you are using, but AWS makes this really easy with Opsworks or Elasticbeanstalk.

Some options include:

- AWS OpsWorks
- AWS Elastic Beanstalk
- Custom HA Proxy Load Balancer

**AWS Opsworks** Using an AWS elastic load balancer (ELB), you can spin up a new NodeJS stack in the AWS Opsworks service and attach an elastic load balancer to these instances. From there you can designate an autoscaling instance to grow and handle more traffic as needed. AWS ELBs round robin traffic to instances depending on a number of configurable metrics (CPU load, time, network traffic).

**AWS Elastic Beanstalk**: See this [tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/create_deploy_nodejs_express_elasticache.html) on how to build a nodejs app using cluster in an autoscaling environment.

**HA Proxy**: If you're looking to run your own [load balancer](http://haproxy.1wt.eu/), you could look into spinning up your own load balancer to handle the traffic.

Comment: you can also use nginx as reverse proxy front of nodejs servers

Comment: Since each Node.js server can run a maximum of 4 Phantomjs instances, how can I make the load balancer to choose a server depending on how many current PhantomJS instances are running? So, send the request to the server that is less loaded in terms of Phantomjs instances that are currently running?

Comment: @HommerSmith, I'm not too familiar with Phantomjs, but I run 8 nodejs processes on a single aws linux c3.2xlarge. 1 master, 7 workers. Node documentation states: "When multiple processes are all accept()ing on the same underlying resource, the operating system load-balances across them very efficiently. There is no routing logic in Node.js, or in your program, and no shared state between the workers." As for the load balancer routing traffic to the servers, you'll find more info on aws configuration [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/workinginstances-autoscaling.html).